# Calling javascript function after composite control rendering

Tags: javascript, asp.net, composite-controls, asp.net-customcontrol

Is there any way to call a javascript function after composite control rendering.I need to place four movable anchors on top of the image control. I am planning to implement the anchors using html Img control. I have already embedded a javascript resource but I cant draw anchors on top of the image control

Answer (score 0):

No,you can not do that with javascript.But you can do that in the backgroud code with override  Render.

Like this:

Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

```
    'you can composite control rendering here.

    MyBase.Render(writer)
```

End Sub

Comment: yea I tried creating anchor(image) in Render, it works but I need to move the image with mouse..any idea to do that ?. Also I unable to get the controls by getElementById method,it returns null when I tried from embedded javascript resource